# Python tracks who prints out?

Tags: python, debugging

I wrote a program that employed a lot of third party libraries, and then I found that during the execution of my program, it kept printing out `foo`. Is there any way that I can track which third party library prints out this `foo`?

Since it is enterprise code, I cannot post my code here.

Comment: Without code it is difficult to help. You can remove those third party libraries, one by one, and see which one is the one printing foos. Also, a quick search for a print('foo') could help

Comment: Without code it will be really hard to know the problem

Comment: maybe Trace through the code using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) watching for the printing `foo` behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search each file for the specific word via command line:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/39200/how-to-search-for-files-containing-specific-word

If it is uploaded to a git repository that allows you to search for a word in the entire repository, like in GitHub or GitLab, then do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work as I tested it very small scale, but if at the top of your main program you override the built in print you may be able to get what you're asking for:

**mymain.py**

```
import inspect
import builtins

myprint = builtins.print
def print(*args, **kwargs): 
    curframe = inspect.currentframe()
    calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)
    myprint(calframe[1][1],':',*args, **kwargs)
builtins.print = print

import modulea

print('Hi')
modulea.myfunc()
```

**modulea.py**

```
import moduleb

moduleb.myfunc()

def myfunc():
    print("HI")
```

**moduleb.py**

```
def myfunc():
    print("HI")
```

Running *mymain.py* in IDLE results in the following output:

> C:\Users\#########\Desktop\New folder\moduleb.py : HI
>
> C:\Users\#########\Desktop\New folder\mymain.py : Hi
>
> C:\Users\#########\Desktop\New folder\modulea.py : HI